# How to read array of objects with data from fireabse

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have a function that create tasks and writing it in firebase real time database.

```
export const createNewTask = (task) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        await database().ref('tasks').child(auth().currentUser.uid).child(task.taskCreationDate.toString()).set(task);
        resolve();
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }
});
```

And it's working good :

[image]

Now, I have a socond functions that should read that tasks.

```
export const fetchTasks = () => (dispatch) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const snapshot = await database().ref('tasks').child(auth().currentUser.uid).once('value');
        if (snapshot.exists) {
            const tasks = snapshot.val();
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_TASKS,
                payload: tasks,
            });
            resolve(tasks);
        } else {
            resolve(snapshot);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }
});
```

And here is the problem:
When I'm using useSelector in my home screen `const tasks = useSelector(state => state.GeneralReducer.taskList);`
The tasks list is undefiend.
When I used mock data with same objects , it's work fine.
How can I get a list of task?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , fixed it by adding :

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => ({...data[key], id: key}));
```

to the function fetchTasks.

```
export const fetchTasks = () => (dispatch) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const snapshot = await database().ref('tasks').child(auth().currentUser.uid).once('value');
        if (snapshot.exists) {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            const tasks = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({...data[key], id: key}));
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_TASKS,
                payload: tasks,
            });

            resolve(tasks);
        } else {
            resolve(snapshot);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }
});
```